# How can I log the current time with timezone in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, timezone

I use a logging configuration (YAML-file) with the following formatter:

```
formatters:
    detailed:
        class: logging.Formatter
        format: '[%(asctime)s]:[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s'
```

The `asctime` gives strings like `2018-04-10 07:00:39,526`, but I would like to get the current timezone as well, e.g. `2018-04-10 07:00:39,526+02:00`. Is that possible without the [work-around from Python 2.X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865750/562769)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom logging class, like this:

```
import logging
class FormatterWithTimezone(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        return (
            time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%%03d%z', self.converter(record.created))
            % record.msecs)
```

Then set up this class to be used instead of `logging.Formatter`.