# Python logger output dates in IS8601 format

Tags: python, python-2.7, iso8601

Is there a way to make the Python logger output dates in ISO8601 format?

My logger is set up like this...

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(message)s - %(asctime)s)
```

From the Python docs (located here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) you can see the following:

> The default format for date/time display (shown above) is ISO8601. If
> you need more control over the formatting of the date/time, provide a
> datefmt argument to basicConfig, as in this example:

The only problem is that the date output is not ISO8601 format. The date output by the above formatter is:

`2018-06-15 11:07:41,454`

This is not ISO8601 format as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

What is the easiest way to get the date in the correct format? Can this be done out of the box or do I need to import a package to do it?

I've tried adding a date formatter e.g. `datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f %Z"` but some of the formatting characters were not recognised - namely `%f` and `%Z` gave a textual description of the timezone and not a numeric offset.

Comment: I think you can build on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865750/187292

Comment: *"some of the formatting characters were not recognised."* - which?

Comment: Example update. I had %f in there which was not recognised. and %Z gives a textual zone description not the numeric offset.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This works for me in most situations:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
)
```

The output looks like:

`2019-11-09T01:18:13-0800 Something logged here`

### Update:

A one-liner I've been using to include miliseconds:

```
logging.Formatter.formatTime = (lambda self, record, datefmt=None: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created, datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat(sep="T",timespec="milliseconds"))
```

The output looks like

`2021-08-05T22:43:02.985614+00:00 Something logged here`

Comment: how can the milliseconds portion be added to the timestamp, i.e. "%f"? logging doesn't recognize the %f formatter when I try.

Comment: For the milliseconds, you can fiddle with `datefmt` and `default_msec_format `. But imho it is better to subclass `loggin.Formater`.

Comment: `self` should not be in the lambda function. If it is, then when `.formatTime` is called the value intended for `record` will instead be in `self`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution if you don't want to subclass [`logging.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) is to overwrite/monkeypatch [`logging.Formatter.formatTime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime) directly like so:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime

def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')

logging.Formatter.formatTime = formatTime

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
    
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # __name__

myvar = 1
logger.info("test %s", myvar)
```

which will print the timestamp as a ISO8601 with milliseconds and UTC offset:

```
2024-01-15T19:31:29.303+01:00 INFO __main__ test 1
```

---

Or you can subclass [logging.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) like his

```
import logging
import logging.config
from datetime import datetime

class MyCustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')


logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'mycustomformatter': {
            '()': MyCustomFormatter,
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'mycustomformatter',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'root': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }

    })
    
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

myvar = 1
logger.info("test %s", myvar)
```

which produces the exact same output with ISO8601 timestamps:

```
2024-01-15T19:31:29.303+01:00 INFO __main__ test 1
```

---

In both cases the `formatTime()` code  uses:

- `record.created` is the [`LogRecord` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) representing the number of seconds (float) since the epoch returned by  [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)
- [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) is a class method that converts the epoch seconds to a datetime (naive)
- [`astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) converts the naive datetime to [timezone-aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) datetime in the local timezone
- [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat): converts the timezone aware datetime to a ISO8601 string.

---